# grab file every x min, and save with continuous number

Tags: linux, cron, webcam, imagemagick

I have a ip camera which saves pics to my rasperry pi's ftp,
than the pi uses imagemagick to overlay some text and saves it as webcam.jpg
this happens every x minutes via cron

now i want to grab the webcam.jpg and copy it to another directory with continuous numbers like webcam-00001.jpg, webcam-00002.jpg ...
this should happen aswell every x minutes

i tried something like

```
mkdir timelapse
counter=1
ls -1tr *.jpg | while read filename; do cp $filename timelapse/$(printf %05d $counter).jpg; ((counter++)); done
```

but this only works when there are already a lot of pictures in the folder
i need to grab 1 pic every x minutes and save it with a continuous number.

i hope this can be done

Comment: why not name the file using the current timestamp, and just call that from a cronjob?

Comment: Its not very clear to me what you are trying to do - instead of using a cron job, why not use a simple while loop with a delay in it, and run that continuously in the background - in that way you can easily process the file as its pulled down.   Alternatively, you could get the cron job to read and write a counter (for example in a file), and use the contents of the counter file for a move as the file is created - assuming using a timestamp is not a suitable option.

Comment: Infact if you're calling the above 3 lines of code via the cronjob you're resetting the counter to 1 each time too.